# The Label and Entry tags don´t work for my android mobile app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing my first android mobile app using C# on Visual Studio 2022 with Xamarin. I followed all steps for the configuration.

My problem is that I'm trying to do a Qr lector, but the `Entry` and `Label` tag do not show any message, not even the `Placeholder` of `Entry` or the `Text` of the `Label` tags. It's just showing the `Button` to start scanning the code.

My tags:

```
<ContentPage>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Lector de código QR" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnScannerQR" Text="Leer Qr" Clicked="btnScannerQR_Clicked"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtResultado" Placeholder="Resultado de QR"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

My private void:

```
private async void btnScannerQR_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.TopText = "Hi";
        scanner.BottomText = "Bye";
        var result = await scanner.Scan();
        if (result != null)
        {
            txtResultado.Text = result.Text;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

I debugged the app and the Qr message get to the method correctly (I created one from internet). For example, if for the qr that I create I put it to say "Hello", I scan it and "Hello" arrives at the method (`result.Text` == "Hello")

I´m not sure if I have to download something else from the Android SDK manager.

AboutPage.xaml.g.cs:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(AboutPage));
        btnScannerQR = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Button>(this, "btnScannerQR");
        txtResultado = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Entry>(this, "txtResultado");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If I use my phone I can´t see the `Label` and `Entry` tags, but if I use the emulator of VS 2022, Xamarin.Android I can see them but I don't know how to scan the QR from the emulator:

[image]

Comment: I’d start by removing the Grid.  It doesn’t serve any purpose in your layout and may be hiding some elements

Comment: I also tried it but it's the same, doesn't work

Comment: Ggogle `scan the qr code xamarin.android`, you would find the article and sample .